# HIPAA-compliant MySQL database - user search

Tags: php, mysql, search, hipaa

I am writing a PHP application this has sensitive date protected by HIPAA.

For the patients I want to be able to do a search for patients.  IE the clinician can type part of a last name and it will bring up all users that match ie:

```
SELECT * FROM patients where patient_last_name like '%smi%'
```

Is this even possible if I am encrypting / needing to encrypt patient information or do I simply need to make it a static list of patients and not query the database in this way ie

Grab all patients from the database, decrypt them server side and add patients than match the search criteria to an array and finally load the array into the display format?

Comment: How did you resolve this in the end?